# Changing port number in wamp without having to write port in url

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, ports

I changed the wampmanager port ( i did this in the wampmanager.ini, wampmanager.tpl and httpd.conf files). It works now when i enter the url localhost:81, but how can i make it work for just localhost since firefox is autocorrecting localhost:81/path  to localhost/path after pressing enter and because links don't work anymore (they go to localhost).

Comment: Can I ask why you changed the APACHE port number from 80 to 81?

Comment: I have other programs using port 80. I don't know much about this so i just followed a tutorial on the internet which explained what to do. It works though, but only with :81 in the url.

Comment: Can I ask which other programs? Most can be configured away from 80 and its better to do that than change Apaches default port.